# How to get data from many to many relationship in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, many-to-many

I want to retrieve all the users and associated roles to the one table in laravel. but i couldn't continue because i'm getting error called

This is my controller function

```
public function index(){
    if(Auth::user()->isAdmin==1){
        $users = User::with('roles')->get();
        return view('users', campact($users));
    } else {
        abort(403, 'Unauthorized action.');
    }
}
```

This is my User Model's roles function

```
public function roles()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class, 'role_users');
}
```

This is my Role Class's Users function

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class,'role_users');
}
```

This is my data table

```
@foreach ($users as $user)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $user->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
        <td>
            <form method="post">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <div class="form-group">                
                <select class="form-control" data-id="{{$user->id}}" id="role" name="role">
                    <option value="0">Select a Role</option>
                    @foreach ($users->roles as $role)
                    <option  value="{{ $role->id }}">{{ $role->name }}</option>
                    @endforeach
                </select>
            </div>  
            </form>          
        </td>
        <td>{{ $user->created_at }}</td>
        <td>{{ $user->updated_at }}</td>

        <td><div class="form-group">
            <form method="post" id="userActivate">
            {{ csrf_field() }}
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" class="flat-red isActive" data-id="{{$user->id}}" @if ($user->isActive) checked @endif>
            </label>

        </form>
    </div>       
        </td>
        <td>
            <form id="userDelete" method="post" >
                {{ csrf_field() }}
                <button type="button" id="delete" data-id="{{$user->id}}" class="btn btn-block btn-danger btn-flat">Delete</button>
            </form>
        </td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Please help me to solve this.

Comment: What do you want to retrieve from `role_user` table?

Comment: `campact` should (I'm assuming) be `compact` ?

Comment: Please provide error message. Do you have `role_user` table?

Comment: campact is corrected to compact. but same error called "Undefined variable: users (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/users.blade.php)"

Comment: Yeah I have role user table and i want to retrieve roles associated to each user

Comment: please check my answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your Controller code

```
public function index(){
  $users = User::with('roles') // Eager loading
               ->get();
  return view('users')->with('users', $users);
}
```

Then, change your blade code from

```
@foreach ($users->roles as $role)
    <option value="{{ $role->id }}">{{ $role->name }}</option>
@endforeach
```

to

```
@if(count($user->roles) > 0)
@foreach ($user->roles as $role)
    <option value="{{ $role->id }}">{{ $role->name }}</option>
@endforeach
@endif
```

Comment: Even though I got a error called  "Undefined property: stdClass::$roles (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/users.blade.php)"

Comment: lets try to return `$user` in your controller then see the result

Comment: Then again getting error called "Undefined variable: users (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/users.blade.php)"

Comment: what is the name of your migration for many to many relation?

Comment: 2018_12_10_060451_create_role_users_table

Comment: try change your code like this
`public function index(){ return User::with('roles')->get(); }`

Comment: [{"id":1,"name":"Anushka Deshan","isAdmin":1,"email":"info@bec.berendina.org","email_verified_at":null,"isActive":1,"created_at":"2018-11-21 09:41:11","updated_at":"2018-12-07 07:56:43","roles":[]},{"id":2,"name":"Charith Athukorala","isAdmin":2,"email":"kegalle@bec.berendina.org","email_verified_at":null,"isActive":1,"created_at":"2018-11-21 09:57:40","updated_at":"2018-12-06 04:29:32","roles":[]},{"id":19,"name":"Anushka .......... i got this result in browser.

Comment: lets try change your index code.. then change the foreach code with my code `$users = User::with('roles')->get(); return view('users')->with('users',$users);`

Comment: James ! It works without populating dropdown. How can i populated all the roles and selected drop down item with associated role for each user

Comment: do you mean that it works without using select option? I have updated my answer again in my `@foreach` let's check it again

Comment: Yes. How can i populated all the roles and same time selected drop down item with associated role for each user

Comment: you have to add a user with roles.. then save it into your Database.. then try it to show the data again.. I think the roles with show up in each users

Comment: I will do the same and Thank You very much

Answer (score 2):

Edit this line:

```
return view('users', campact($users));
```

to:

```
return view('users', compact('users'));
```

Comment: THe its getting a error " Property [roles] does not exist on this collection instance. (View: /var/www/html/laravel/resources/views/users.blade.php) "

Answer (score 0):

```
public function edit(string $id)
    {
        $post = Post::findOrFail($id);;
        $tagIds = $post->tags()->pluck('id')->toArray();
        $categories = Category::all();
        $tags = Tag::all();
        return view('auth.posts.edit', compact('post', 'tagIds', 'categories', 'tags'));
    }
    
<label class="form-label">Tags</label>
                            <select class="form-control" id="multi-selector" name="tags[]" multiple required="">
                                <option></option>
                                @foreach($tags as $tag)
                                    <option value="{{$tag->id}}"
                                        @selected(in_array($tag->id, old('tags', $tagIds)))>
                                        {{$tag->name}}
                                    </option>
                                @endforeach
                            </select>
```